# Trying to use a function with parameters to change two icons separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I'm not quite sure why my code isn't working. I basically have a function that moves two different icons depending on which `header` you click on. Here's the code:

```
var expanded = false;
var eFunction = function (header, icon) {
    $(header).on('click', function () {
        if (expanded) {
            $(icon).css({backgroundPosition: '0 100%'});
            expanded = true;
        } else {
            $(icon).css({backgroundPosition: '0 0'});
            expanded = false;
        }
    });
};

eFunction(this.$.aOne, this.$.eOne);
eFunction(this.$.aTwo, this.$.eTwo);
```

I'm using Polymer, which translates `this.$.aOne` to aOne ID. I've console logged both and they're not the issue.

Is there something with functions with parameters and css IDs?

Here's the HTML, but I don't think it's relevant:

```
<div class="accordheader" on-click="{{toggle}}" horizontal justified layout id="aOne">
    <div>{{items[0]}}</div>
    <div class="expandicon" id="eOne"></div>
</div>
<core-collapse id="collapse" opened="false">
    <p>{{contents[0]}}</p>
</core-collapse>

<div class="accordheader" on-click="{{toggleTwo}}" horizontal justified layout id="aTwo">
    <div>{{items[1]}}</div>
    <div class="expandicon" id="eTwo"></div>
</div>
<core-collapse id="collapsetwo" opened="false">
    <p>{{contents[1]}}</p>
</core-collapse>
```

**edit** I was saying if (expanded) instead of if (expanded == false). Whoops

Answer (score 1):

No, the problem is you only have one `expanded` flag, but you're trying to apply it to two separate elements.

Use two separate flags. You already have a convenient location for them (the closure created by calling `eFunction`):

```
var eFunction = function (header, icon) {
    var expanded = false;                      // <== Note: Now a variable in the call
    $(header).on('click', function () {        // <== This closes over that variable
        if (expanded) {
            $(icon).css({backgroundPosition: '0 100%'});
            expanded = true;
        } else {
            $(icon).css({backgroundPosition: '0 0'});
            expanded = false;
        }
    });
};

eFunction(this.$.aOne, this.$.eOne);
eFunction(this.$.aTwo, this.$.eTwo);
```

Or if it's possible you may need this data elsewhere, store it *on* the elements, using `data`:

```
var eFunction = function (header, icon) {
    $(header).on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data("expanded")) {
            $(icon).css({backgroundPosition: '0 100%'});
            $this.data("expanded", true);
        } else {
            $(icon).css({backgroundPosition: '0 0'});
            $this.data("expanded", false);
        }
    });
};

eFunction(this.$.aOne, this.$.eOne);
eFunction(this.$.aTwo, this.$.eTwo);
```

Note that that relies on the fact that calling `data` for something that doesn't exist gives you `undefined`, which is falsey.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I actually found my error and it was a small logic problem, but I'll use this info for storing data in the future. Thanks :-)